# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (RAILS)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy recogiendo datos de un web services de cines y quiero obtener las películas, pero me da error:

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Esta es la función en el `controller`:

```
 def set_movies
    prepare_client_soap
    @response = [];
    dates=@dates.return[:fecha]
    dates.each do |date|
      message={:user => ,
               :password => ,
               :id_fecha => 
      }
      response=@client.call(:get_peliculas, message: message)
      response= response.to_hash
      @response.push(response[:get_peliculas_response])
    end
    @response_array = [];
    @response.each do |response|
      movies=response[:return][:pelicula]
      movies.each do |movie|
        @response_array.push(movie)
      end
    end
    @movies=@response_array
  end
```

En mi `HTML`:

```
-@movies.each do |movie|
  =movie[:pelicula]
```

Comment: Puede que este esperando un indice en el arreglo y no un símbolo en el hash

Comment: en que linea te tira el error?

Comment: ya lo solucione, el problema era que el ws me devolvia arrays y objetos, le puse la validacion "if movies.kind_of?(Array)" y ya no tuve el problema, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@response.each do |response|
 movies=response[:return][:pelicula]
 movies.each do |movie|
   @response_array.push(movie)
 end
end
```

Revisa tu variable **movies**  si es un array **movies.kind_of?(Array)** puedes que tu resultado sea un objeto y no un Array